# php multi dimensional array iteration

Tags: php, arrays, magento, iteration

I have been trying to iterate throught this array to get a desired result but with no success.Hopefully someone here can help me out. I have the following multidimensional array of categories and subcategories and category id.

```
  Array
(
 [categories] => Array
(
    [2] => Array
        (
            [category_id] => 2
            [sub_categories] => Array
                (
                    [36] => Men
                )
        )

    [36] => Array
        (
            [category_id] => 36
            [sub_categories] => Array
                (
                    [37] => Clothing
                    [38] => Shoes
                )
        )

    [37] => Array
        (
            [category_id] => 37
            [sub_categories] => Array
                (
                    [39] => Outerwear
                    [42] => Tops
                )
        )

     [38] => Array
        (
            [category_id] => 38
            [sub_categories] => Array
                (

                )
        )

    [39] => Array
        (
            [category_id] => 39
            [sub_categories] => Array
                (
                    [49] => Jackets
                )
        )

    [42] => Array
        (
            [category_id] => 42
            [sub_categories] => Array
                (
                    [46] => Sweaters
                )
        )
)

)
```

I would like to use a for each loop so that I can loop through this array to create a category tree for a magento store. The desired output for the tree is below:

```
    Men
    -Clothing
      -Outerwear
        -Jackets
      -Tops
        -Sweaters
    -Shoes
```

or in html

```
    <ul>
      <li class="cat">
        Men
      </li>
      <li class="cat">
        Clothing 
         <ul>
           <li class="subcat">Outerwear</li>
            <ul>
              <li class="subsubcat">Jackets</li>
            </ul>
           </li>
           <li class="subcat">Tops</li>
            <ul>
              <li class="subsubcat">Sweaters</li>
            </ul>
           </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
     <li class="cat">Shoes</li>
  </ul>
```

Any pointers are deeply appreciated.

Comment: What is the problem. Please include the code, show where it failed, include error messages.

Comment: I don't know how to do it. That's why i asking here. Please refrain from commenting if you are going to state the obvious.

Comment: No thanks. Please read guidelines about how to ask a good question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several days and with help from Abdo Adel with recursion here is the code that generated the output.

```
  function printCategory($cat_id, $lvl, )
{ 



foreach($arr[$cat_id]['sub_categories'] as $sub_cat_id => $sub_cat_name)
{
   echo '<li class="'.$lvl.'">'.$sub_cat_name.'';
   if($arr[$sub_cat_name]['sub_categories']){
       echo'<ul>';
     printCategory($sub_cat_id, 'sub' . $lvl);

     echo '</ul>';
     }
     echo  '</li>';

}

 }
```

printCategory(2, 'cat');

Comment: except that you need to change 'echo printCategory(2, 'cat');' to 'printCategory(2, 'cat');', echo is not needed in ur solution

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't know how to start, I'll give you some big hint for one possible solution (there are other solutions, this is not the only way of doing it!)

Our solution is a recursive one, you need to define a start point and start breaking your problem into sub problems, and then solve each problem alone

Think of the categories array as a single level array (no sub categories), what would you do to print a single level array? a simple loop, now you want to print the subcategories of this category, treat them like if they were different other individual problems simply by applying the same initial solution on them !

here is a fragment of code

```html
<?php
  $arr = ... // this contains your categories initialization
  function printCategory($cat_id, $lvl)
  {
    $ret = '';
    foreach($arr[$cat_id]['sub_categories'] as $sub_cat_id => $sub_cat_name)
    {
       $ret = "<li class='{$lvl}'>{$sub_cat_name}</li>";
       $sub_sub_cats = printCategory($sub_cat_id, 'sub' . $lvl);
       // check if $sub_sub_cats is empty, then don't display a new <ul>
       // else dispay a new <ul> and enclose the returned data in it
    }
    return $ret;
  }
  echo printCategory($x, $y);
  // try to figure out what are the values of $x and $y 
?>
```

Comment: I'm not simply trying to print the subcategories in each array. That is simple. Please read my question carefully

Comment: i think that you didn't get the idea of the recursion, or may be you never heard about it before ?, this solution can be applied to infinite # of levels :D

Comment: trace the function well and pay some good attention to this line '$sub_sub_cats = printCategory($sub_cat_id, 'sub' . $lvl);' the magic happens here

Comment: Hey I'm still having trouble. I using 2 and cat for the value of $x and $y but the order is reversed. Any other pointers?

Comment: $x = 2 , $y = 'cat' => that's correct, but if the order is reversed, that means you completed the code in a wrong way. Trace what happens in the execution stack as if you were the PHP interpreter, if you failed to determine the error, post it here
=http://codepad.org/ and tell me why do you think it fails?

Comment: I know that it does not work you have to modify it and add some stuff, do you expect that some one will post a complete code here :D, Good Luck !

Comment: wow, you changed the return concept to echo, that's great, I'm sure that you fully understand it now, what you have done is called top-down recursion (processing/echo before going down), what i was doing is bottom-up (going down, processing, then returning the output/echo)